MacBook Pro “15 (A1398, Mid 2015) crashes sometimes, and boots inconsistently, but works perfectly in safe mode
I am having a problem with my MacBook Pro “15 (A1398, Mid 2015) - during operation in normal mode, it sometimes and highly unpredictably freezes, and shuts down. When switched on, it boots but half of the time it does not boot correctly and you need to boot 2-3 times to make it to normal mode. It also shuts down when I send it to sleep. Also, I use it in clamshell mode, so have an external display. It behaves not very different out of clamshell mode too.
An important point is that it works perfectly in safe mode (boots properly, doesn’t crash, and sleeps and wakes properly). So I think we can eliminate hardware issues.

Start with the low-hanging fruit. If any third-party "anti-virus" software is installed, remove it according to the developer's instructions and reboot. You should do this regardless of whether it's causing the problem, as all such software is worse than useless. Otherwise, please list the contents of the folder /Library/Extensions.

Hi @LincD., thank you for your reply. I don’t use any antivirus as I didn’t need it. Here is the /Library/Extensions contents. https://pastebin.com/LKMNBS6N

You have some third-party kernel extensions, which are to be avoided if you want a stable system. I suggest you start by removing “Intel HAXM” completely, again according to the developer’s instructions. Reboot and test.

Hi @LincD. , just removed Intel HAXM by the developers instructions. The boot failed again (keep in mind it fails as often as it works, I’m currently on my system, fearing it might crash anytime, anywhere from now to the next day).

By the way @LincD. thank you for your help. I am ready to comply with any other directions. Will try removing other 3rd party extensions soon.

One mistake we might be doing is seeing the wrong kernel extensions. My kernel is in /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/System/Library/Extensions. Here is much longer list of third party extensions. https://pastebin.com/JW6VXfRB

In your original list, numbers 2, 3, 6, 7, and 8 are all third-party. You’ll need to figure out what they go with and remove it completely. The second list is built-in system components.

I may / can remove them but I think it’s futile. I used kextstat to find if any of these third party kernels are working and they are not.

Kexts can load, or fail to load, dynamically. Regardless, it's clear that system modifications are causing the problem. If you prefer to use your own judgment as to which ones to remove, good luck.

After a while you spend more time fiddling with the problem than fixing it. Take it from someone that did support for a living, cut your losses. Back up the system, wipe the drive and start over fresh. @Bmike is correct and left an excellent procedure below. After a while it becomes more time/cost effective to just wipe it and start over.

Thank you Steve, I am indeed going to do that. However, I want to remind both you and Bmike that Stackexchange is for expert advice on debugging (at least that is what I had assumed and hoped). This is why I came here - to get information which I do not know. What you and  @Bmike tell me, while is the pragmatic way out, is not the solution or the answer I was looking for. I am not entitled to any answer, I agree, and I am thankful to both of you for your time and energy. I still hold my point however.

No one is telling you you’re not entitled to any answer. That is hyperbole, bordering on absurd, given how this site is designed and operates. Everyone gets to ask their question. Everyone can follow a process to edit and everyone can propose their best answer. Could you please dial down the “speaking for others” which can be seen as personal attacks if they persist.

Even better, @DanishA.Alvi you as the question owner can choose any answer you want. Even one that everyone votes down, so you are in the driver seat. I would expect an expert answer in 6 to 18 months based upon the details you provided. Perhaps someone brilliant will come along sooner with your desired solution.

Hi Mike, I am sorry if I angered you. You only tried to help, and I am thankful for your time and effort.

Turns out it was a failed GPU. The motherboard was replaced.

I presume your Mac was one of the MBPs that had two GPUs? Safe mode only uses the integrated graphics. (The discrete GPUs were frequently prone to failure.)

That is true. A1398. Had an AMD Discrete GPU (and so does the replacement). I’ve deactivated the AMD GPU on this one so that nothing causates a malfunction.

The simple path for your general situation (and especially from the comments: boot failed again: keep in mind it fails as often as it works, I’m currently on my system, fearing it might crash anytime) is:

check your backup and get an external drive or two to save time
Set up Time Machine on the first drive and let it run a day or two
Install macOS on a second external drive

Use the startup manager to boot from the clean external drive and verify the backup is good or use the clean OS to get a known complete backup of the problem installation.
Once you know you have a solid backup and confirm the clean OS works, erase the bad and restore your data.
This is likely software corruption and you can choose how much time and skill you want to spend “fixing” it once you know you don’t have to and can invest a few hours waiting to get a good result when you do an erase install.

Thank you for your reply. While I appreciate your pragmatism, please bear in mind that this should always be proposed as a second option. Everyone is likely already familiar of this being the last resort.

I disagree and appreciate your comment. Installing clean is to be sure it’s not software. You need a backup (or you would delete things already to test) and this truly is the easiest path for most to solve without needing extra skills. Determining which software is bad is much harder and higher risk. For some it’s appropriate. When a system struggles - this is the last warning you might have if it’s about to fail hardware-wise. Best to be prepared even if you don’t have to execute the plan. It also helps isolate a failure with minimal time and modest hardware needs
